# Migration from Cordova to Capacitor Results in Two Separate iOS Apps with Identical Bundle Identifiers

Tags: ios, cordova, migration, capacitor

I am currently in the process of migrating an existing Cordova-based application to Capacitor. To ensure a smooth transition, I initially install the old Cordova-based app on my iPad. Subsequently, I push the newly migrated Capacitor-based app. Instead of replacing the Cordova app, iOS generates a second app, even though both apps share the exact same bundle identifier. Could this issue be attributed to another factor, and how does iOS determine the uniqueness of builds with identical bundle identifiers?

Comment: The bundle identifiers are not identical. You can't have two apps on the device with the same bundle identifier.

Comment: I suspected the same. I've tested with identical bundle identifiers. The problem occurs when running the app from XCode to a connected device, but not when using TestFlight. The only problem with TestFlight is that updating from Cordova to Capacitor results in data loss in IndexedDB.

Comment: The Cordova version is already on the App Store Connect, and if the bundle identifier were different, I shouldn't be able to push the new build with Capacitor

Comment: The version you are deploying with Xcode probably has a different team id.  Check your signing

Comment: impossible, this is always the same team : /

Comment: Install the App Store version and then pull the ipa file off your device with iMazing.  Compare it to the app file you are installing with Xcode.  Something is different.  You are going to have to solve the App Store/Testflight update issue anyway since otherwise your users will lose their data when they update

Comment: I am not familiar with iMazing, but it seems to be a good lead. What I would have liked to do on Android is to enter the command 'aapt dump badging.' I don't think I have ever generated IPA files with Xcode, but I will have to get into it. Data loss is indeed what I fear, although in my context, it's not so serious because they are backed up online. I mainly want to understand why iOS behaves like this. Thanks for your help